# Delphi 'class of' use to create an object of a specific type

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have `TParentObj = class(TComponent)` and `TChildObj = class (TParentObj)`.  In addition I have a `TCustomObj = class of TParentObj`.

I'm then wanting to create an object of Type parent OR Type Child depending on what a variable is.  If 'child' is selected then a `TChildObj` should be created and so on.

In the function I have a var:  `obj : TCustomObj`.
and then I'm trying to do:

```
if oReturnType = TChildObj
  obj := TChildObj.create
else if oReturnType = TParentObj
  obj := TParentObj.create
```

`oReturnType` is set and passed in elsewhere.

If I use 'is' instead of '=' I receive the error that the operator is not applicable to this operand type and if I use = instead I get an incompatible types error between `TCustomObj` and both `TChildObj` and `TParentObj`.

I've searched quite a bit but have yet to discover what I'm doing wrong and hoping someone here might be able to shed some light on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please create a short 20 line complete compilable console app that demonstrates the issue. Then we won't need to guess.

Comment: One of the problems with trying to anonymize code the way you've done here is that it obscures semantic differences that may or may not matter.  For example, at the top you speak of `TParentObj` and `TChildObj`, and below, you speak of `TParent` and `TChild`.

Comment: obj : TCustomObj where TCustomObj = class of TParentObj means that obj is **NOT** an instance of TParentObj, TChildObj.create and TParentObj.create create instances. Therefore these are incompatible.

Comment: Rename your TCustomObj as TParentObjClass as it should be, then it will be more clear.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - thankyou, I wasn't aware of that conventaion

Comment: We still don't know what `oReturnType` is. We can guess. I can't understand why you wouldn't write a complete program to illustrate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, it appears that you've missed one of the most important points of `TClass` variables: they have access to constructors, and to *virtual constructors*.

If you put a constructor on `TParentObj` and declare it **virtual;**, and then have all descendants **override;** that constructor as needed, then a `TClass` variable declared as `class of TParentObj` will have access to this virtual constructor, and will behave exactly as you'd expect a virtual method to behave:

```
obj := oReturnType.Create(); 
//invoke the virtual constructor on the actual type of oReturnType
```

This technique is used extensively in the VCL; it's at the core of Delphi's form streaming system, for example.  `TComponent` defines a virtual constructor whose signature is `(AOwner: TComponent)`, and every custom component and control that needs a new constructor overrides this one.  It's a very useful system, and if you look at the way it works you'll quickly gain an appreciation for the techniques involved.

But as for the actual problem, you're getting an incompatible types error between `TCustomObj` and both `TChildObj` and `TParentObj` because *they're not compatible types.*

`TChildObj` and `TParentObj` are *object classes*, and `TCustomObj` is a *metaclass*, or *class variable*.  A `TParentObj` variable represents an object, whereas `TCustomObj`, which is defined as `class of TParentObj`, represents the class itself, not an object of that class.  Declare `obj` as `TParentObj` (which will accept an object instance of `TParentObj` or any of its descendants) and you'll be good.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  The edit you just made has helped so much in understanding what and where I was going wrong.  Thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the classtype `TCustomObj` to create the instance

```
function ObjFactory( AClass : TCustomObj ): TParentObj;
begin
  Result := AClass.Create;
end;

procedure foo;
var
  LObj : TParentObj;
begin
  // instance of TParentObj
  LObj := ObjFactory( TParentObj );
  // or instance of TChildObj
  LObj := ObjFactory( TChildObj );
end;
```

Comment: Firstly, this breaks if `TParentObj`'s constructor is non-virtual, and secondly, this is just an alternative way of writing the code, not an answer to the question of what's wrong with the code the OP wrote.

Comment: @hvd Well the question is how to create the instance depending on a variable/argument and not how to build a class structure

Comment: Let me rephrase the first part of my comment: depending on the class structure, the OP's approach could work where your approach would fail. That should at least be clearly mentioned. For the second part, okay, I guess it's possible to read the question that way. I don't think it's as helpful as possible, but it's not *un*helpful either, so I'll shut up about that part.

Comment: @hvd It doesn't "break if `TParentObj`'s constructor is non-virtual". Memory allocation will still be correct. The only thing you lose is the ability to override and customise the constructor in subclasses because `TParentObjClass` would be unaware of subclass constructors.

Comment: @CraigYoung Right, I should have been more precise. If `TChildObj` has a custom constructor that doesn't override the one in `TParentObj`, and existing code using approach in the question relies on that constructor being called, then changing the code to use the approach in this answer will break that. Does that sound better?